# Javascript undifined variable after loop

Tags: javascript, html, variables, loops

I have a countdown script that redirects to a file. It has a loop in it and the variable gets undifined when it ran once.

How can i keep the url variable to hold its value?

```
        <a id="" onClick="doTimer('http://www.domain.com/downloadfile.php?photo=foo.jpg')" href="#"><button id="download">Download this photo</button></a>

        var timer_is_on=0;
        var countdownfrom=5
        var currentsecond=document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML=countdownfrom+1 

        function countredirect(url)
        { 
            if (currentsecond!=1)
            {
                currentsecond-=1 
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = currentsecond;
            } 
            else
            { 
                window.location=url 
                return 
            } 
            setTimeout("countredirect()",1000) 
        }
        function doTimer(url)
        {
            if(!timer_is_on)
            {
                document.getElementById('download').innerHTML="Your download starts in <span id=\"countdown\"></span>seconds";
                timer_is_on=1;
                countredirect(url) 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which variable gets undefined?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: The url variable wich i use in the dotimer function first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setTimeout("countredirect()",1000)
```

You are not passing any argument to your `countredirect` function.

Passing strings to `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is generally a bad idea (gives you all sorts of scope problems). Pass a function instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    countredirect(url);
}, 1000);
```

In newer browsers (or with shim) you can also use [`.bind()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (`bind` returns a new function):

```
setTimeout(countredirect.bind(null, url), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to re-scheduling your function:

```
setTimeout(countredirect.bind(null, url), 1000);
```